# Error while running configure. Halting the installation

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to update Ruby via RVM to 1.9.3-p327. After typing `rvm install 1.9.3-p327`, I get this:

```
    No binary rubies available for: downloads/ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Then, I check the config log in `ruby 1.9.3-p327/configure.log` in which I see this:

```
[2012-12-24 22:39:14] env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-       I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I've install the newest Xcode 4.5.2 as well as install CLT via Xcode..It seems like the C compiler doesnt work and I dont know how to fix it.any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you tried it aleady, but your best bet is to google for "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables". There you will find lots of answers to this question. You might also be missing `ld` (the linker..it was in one of the answers on google).

Comment: I actually googled that exact string a after posting this. I noticed there was something fishy with Xcode and ended up reinstalling it. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score -6, accepted):

check out this RVM installation page: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/. This might help you out.

Comment: thanks for the reference link, turns out I was using a different version of Xcode. Cheers!